# Is there a collateral adjective for 'game'?

Tags: adjectives, latin, greek

I was looking for an adjective that would describe anything game-like that is either taken directly from Ancient Greek or Latin. 'Ludic' comes to mind, but it came to assume the same connotations as the English 'playful'.

For example, 'Employers tried to raise the incentive of the employees by rendering the working environment *x*', where *x* would be an adjective meaning 'having a game-like structure'.

Comment: It's a little unclear as to what you're asking. Could you maybe give us some example usage?

Comment: @Waterbagel, sure, I'll edit my question in a moment

Comment: If you rewrite the sentence slightly, you can use one of modern English's current buzz-words: *Employers tried to incentivize the employees by **[gamifying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification)** the working environment.*

Comment: @Catija, awesome, thanks for your helpful comment! Post it as an answer so I can up-vote/accept it. Is 'to gamify' regarded as colloquialism?

Comment: Not at all.  It's a [scholarly](https://www.coursera.org/course/gamification) subject, actually.

Comment: duskn, I think your understanding of the word ***game*** is over-influenced by relatively new usages such a *to game the system* (manipulate it to one's advantage), and the way user-content-sustained websites (like ELU) use *gamification* to encourage participation. Until quite recently, your ***x*** would almost always have been something like *[playful] **competition***. Bear in mind it's not really a "game" to the people who set the situation up. It's usually a matter of *money* (and getting people to make valuable contributions in return for for *points* rather than money! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not a native speaker, and hence I was exposed very little to such idiomatic locutions :) My understanding of the word game was  most likely influenced by playing actual board games and Conway's cellular automaton.

Comment: That's what I meant. board games, and the software *game of Life*, are all about *competitive strategy* - nothing to do with the original/core sense of *playful*. In your example context, *game-oriented* is effectively a euphemism for *competitive*. That's really the word for the quality you're trying to name here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept you're looking for is "[gamification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification)".

> Gamification is the use of game thinking and game mechanics in non-game contexts to engage users in solving problems and increase users' contributions. Gamification has been studied and applied in several domains, with some of the main purposes being to engage (improve user engagement, physical exercise, return on investment, flow, data quality, timeliness), teach (in classrooms, the public or at work), entertain (enjoyment, fan loyalty), measure (for recruiting and employee evaluation), and to improve the perceived ease of use of information systems. A review of research on gamification shows that a majority of studies on gamification find positive effects from gamification. However, individual and contextual differences exist.

While it won't fit into the sentence as written, it's possible to rewrite the sentence slightly to use it:

> Employers tried to incentivize the employees by *gamifying* the working environment.

This is a concept that's currently even being taught in universities.

[Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/gamification) course offered by The [Wharton School](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wharton_School_of_the_University_of_Pennsylvania) at the University of Pennsylvania, a business school.

> Gamification is the application of game elements and digital game design techniques to non-game problems, such as business and social impact challenges. This course will teach you the mechanisms of gamification, why it has such tremendous potential, and how to use it effectively.